# How to handle when the backspace button is pressed and the input panel has digit grouped numbers. E.g. 434,343,334.232

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am making a calculator in c# for the windows phone and I'm struggling right now.

Say the user wrote the digits 123,456. What I want to happen is when the user hits the backspace key, the comma stays in place and when the number 3 is deleted, so is the comma. Right now when the user hits the backspace key, the comma is deleted as the digits are being deleted. So when you erase the 6 and 5, 123,4 is left.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `String.Format("{0:n}", value)` for displaying the numbers with commas. If the user enters commas, strip them when storing them in your program.

Basically, you can store the number internally in the program as a numeric type (such as `Decimal`). When the user hits the backspace key (or otherwise enters text), parse the numeric value out of the string and then update the display with the `String.Format` operation using the numeric value.

Comment: Here's what I have:                              strNumberWithoutDecimals = Convert.ToDouble(strNumberWithoutDecimals).ToString("#,##0"); So how would I strip the commas?

Comment: `strNumberWithoutCommas = strNumberWithCommas.Replace("," , "")`. This replaces the commas with empty strings, effectively removing them.

Comment: The closest I've gotten is I went to my backspace click event and said that if the backspace key is pressed and their are commas present take them out. But the problem is that say you have a number such as 32,234 and press the backspace key, the comma is gone as well as the 4.

Comment: Then the next line of code could be to convert (or parse) the string back into a numeric type and reformat for the commas. Next update the display with the resulting string.

Comment: if (Convert.ToDouble(inputPanelTextBox.Text) < 4)
            {
                inputPanelTextBox.Text =         inputPanelTextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
                Convert.ToDouble(inputPanelTextBox.Text).ToString("###");
            } And nothing happens.

Comment: Nothing is happening because you are saying if the number is less than 4. Are you wanting this? Or are you wanting the number of digits/characters is less than 4, or the number less than 1000? Additionally, where is your else case? Wouldn't you need that as well?

Comment: Well what I'm saying here is that whenever the number is less than four digits take the comma off. But that's a problem because what if there's a number like this 12,234. Now come to realize it it won't take the comma off properly. What would be in my if else statement?

Comment: @Navio53 Why not always strip the commas out of the string when the user presses the backspace key and then reformat?