# How to erase the comma in a calculator when the user has numbers such as 233,232 when they hit the 3 that is on the left of the comma

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle when the backspace button is pressed and the input panel has digit grouped numbers. E.g. 434,343,334.232.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307129/how-to-handle-when-the-backspace-button-is-pressed-and-the-input-panel-has-digit)

Basically the question says it all, I'm making a calculator in c# and I'm stuck on this problem. When digit grouping is hit the numbers get separated by commas, when the user hits the backspace button, the commas act like characters that get deleted.

inputPanelTextBox.Text = inputPanelTextBox.Text.Replace(",", "") I put this piece of code under my backspace click event. The problem is that say the panel has 234,232 and the user presses the backspace button, the comma is gone as well as the 2 on the far right.

What I want to happen is the same way the windows 7 calculator does when the digit grouped menu is checked and the user hits the backspace.

Any idea of how to go about this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't store the `,` in the input string at all; I'd separate the input string from the display string, and convert the input string to display string on every key press. But perhaps there are more clever ideas. :)

Comment: The thing is I want it automatically to erase the comma after the 3 on the left is gone. Here's what I got:                         inputPanelTextBox.Text = inputPanelTextBox.Text.Replace(",", ""); I put this under my backspace click event. The problem is that say you have a number such as 43,343 and press backspace, the comma is gone, what I want it to do is to be 4,343. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you store the number just as a number then format the number to look nice when you output it. The same thing will work with `string.Format()`. You could reformat the number into the display string every time the user hits backspace or adds a new digit. There are lots of the string format modifiers listed [here](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/).

```
int numWithComma = 3000;
int numWithoutComma = 50;
Console.WriteLine("numWithComma: {0:n}", numWithComma);
Console.WriteLine("numWithoutComma: {0:n}", numWithoutComma);

// prints:
// numWithComma: 3,000.00
// numWithoutComma: 50.00
```

If I were making this calculator, I would save the number in a `double`, then when the number needs to be displayed I would run it through a function like this and display the string to the user:

```
private static string FormatForDisplay(double number)
{
    return string.Format("{0:n}", number);
}
```

Comment: I have my own custom number formatting method, here it is:         private string CustomNumberFormat(string myNumber)
        {

            int dot = myNumber.IndexOf(".");

            string strNumberWithoutDecimals = myNumber.Substring(0, (dot == -1 ? myNumber.Length : dot));
            string strNumberDecimals = (dot == -1 ? "" : myNumber.Substring(dot));

            strNumberWithoutDecimals = Convert.ToDouble(strNumberWithoutDecimals).ToString("#,##0");

            total = strNumberWithoutDecimals + strNumberDecimals;

            return total;
        }

Comment: How would I use what I have so that when the user hits the backspace I can modify the input panel just like you said? Also I have a text changed event which allows the panel to format automatically.

Comment: @Navio53, My main point is: you should **not** be saving the display string. ie, `string strNum = "2,000.50"`. You **should** be saving the number itself, ie, `Double nNum = 2000.50`. You're making a calculator, you should be dealing with numbers, not strings.

Comment: @Navio53, if you absolutely want to use your `CustomNumberFormat()` method. You can add `myNumber = myNumber.Replace(",", string.Empty)` as the first line so you remove all commas since your method will put the commas in the correct place.

Comment: Cool. Sorry if I got over zealous there for a second. :) Anything else I can help with?

Comment: Ok, so I added the myNumber = myNumber.Replace(",", string.Empty) on the first line and nothing happened, it's just as if it ignored this line of code. Sorry if I'm not completely getting what you're saying, it's because I'm a little bit new to programming.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that I might have to work with the backspace click event. I was thinking of putting an if statement saying that whenever you approach a comma delete the comma with the number on its left and then putting the .Replace extension on the input panel. But I don't know how to put what I said about the if statement into code.

Comment: @Navio53, oops, my bad, I misunderstood how you have the `.ToString()` set up. That `.Replace()` line is unnecessary. So suppose your display string is `"123,456"`, then the user hits backspace. All you need to do is remove the last character and run it through `CustomNumberFormat` again. Know how to remove the last char?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a format string when you output the number, that way you don't have to manage commas at all.

```
double myDouble = 500000.012345
inputPanelTextBox.Text = myDouble.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Its been a while since I've used Visual Studio but I'm pretty sure you can set these format strings directly on text boxes so its simply automatically handled when they type. And its easy as pie to set in the properties if I remember correctly. Check out [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#Y9675) for a bit more on it.

Also a MaskedTextBox might work as well, set the mask to something like "999,999,999,999.99" and see how that formats different numbers.

Good Luck! :D